# SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer throws exception "column does not allow null"

Tags: c#, sql-server

We use SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer to write a DataTable to a table in SQL Server. The column reported in the exception is NOT NULL but there are no null values in the DataTable. I added code to do an explicit check of every row in the DataTable, none have a NULL value, yet I get this error. Even more odd is that the same column is included in another BulkCopy with the same data and it works. The only difference is there are two more columns in the case where it works.

Basically, I have a dictionary and populate the DataTable using foreach.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, myClass> item in myDictionary)
{
    DataRow dr = myDataTable.NewRow();
    dr["columnname"] = ...
.
.
. 
    myDataTable.Rows.Add(dr)
}
```

I tried adding things like this to try to find the cause:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value.myStringValue))
{
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

This never gets called. Yet when I do

`bulkCopy.WriteToServer(myDataTable)`

I get an exception, column 'x' does not allow nulls. I can modify the column in the database to allow null values, but that's not the preferred solution.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks.

Adding explicit checks for NULL on every row in the DataTable.

above

```
SqlServerClient BulkCopy.WriteToServer table t does not allow null values in column c
```

Comment: Did you add explicit column mappings for all your columns using `SqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings`? If you did not, columns are mapped in the physical order of the tables, which is almost never what you want. An explicit, by-name mapping is necessary even if you're using a `DataTable` with named columns. (There is a reason for this, but it's definitely not a good one.)

Comment: That fixed it. Not sure I completely understand, since the order of the rows in the DataTable matches the database table, but thank you.

Comment: But does the order of the *columns* in your `DataTable` match the physical column order of your table (`column_id` in `sys.columns`), without skipping any? I'm guessing no, and that's where `SqlBulkCopy` falls down -- it maps one of your columns to an unrelated column in the destination, and then gives an error for "missing" values of a column that ended up unmapped.

Comment: That's what I meant -- columns. And yes, there are columns that are nullable that aren't always populated, and that throws off the ordering. Thanks again.